# How to get this jSON data from API with Javascript / AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am working with jSON, an API and AngularJS. I want to get the following data, but I will not know in advanced what the keywords or the dates will be

```
{
"landscape gardening middlesex": {
    "2015-02-12": {
        "position": null,
        "change": "n/a",
        "class": "gray"
    },
    "2015-03-17": {
        "position": "0",
        "change": "n/a",
        "class": "gray"
    }
},
"landscape gardening staines": {
    "2015-02-12": {
        "position": null,
        "change": "n/a",
        "class": "gray"
    },
    "2015-03-17": {
        "position": "94",
        "change": "n/a",
        "class": "green"
    }
},
"landscape gardening surrey": {
    "2015-02-12": {
        "position": null,
        "change": "n/a",
        "class": "green"
    },
    "2015-03-17": {
        "position": "0",
        "change": "n/a",
        "class": "gray"
    }
}
```

}
How can i retrieve this using AngularJS ng-repeat Thanks.

Comment: This question does not make sense. Please rewrite it.

Comment: Can you store the 'date' objects in an array instead?  Otherwise you can just loop through the properties on the parent object and operate on them.

Comment: And what @brianvaughn said...

Comment: Yeah sorry not very clear. By retrieve, I mean cycle through them pretty much like what @dustmouse said and then put them in to the Angular template. I have seen the ng-repeat, but i'm very new to Angular and API's.

Comment: if you want help using `ng-repeat`, your best bet would be to try and use it, then come to us with the code you tried that didn't work.  Coming to us with data that isn't even valid isn't going to get any helpful answers about `ng-repeat`....

Comment: Ok fair-do's. So i've updated my original question with valid json that i get from an api.
I'd like to output the data in to a table. This is what i have:

    <tr ng-repeat="x in seo">
 <td>{{ x[1]}}</td>
 <td>{{ x.position }}</td>
 <td>{{ x.change }}</td>
    </tr>

Answer (score 0):

create a javascript object and store it somewhere...
you can always stringify it then re-parse it

```
var myJSON = {
  name: "bill",
  skills : ["coding", "sleeping", "eating"],
  age : 25 
};

// this string can be stored anywhere,  like even as a string in mySQL.
var string = JSON.stringify( myJSON );  


///  Turn Back into JSON obj
var newJSON = JSON.parse(string);
console.log( newJSON.name );    //  >>  "bill"
```

/// Hope this helps